# Curses giving error when running curses.initscr() - python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm, python-idle, python-curses

Background:

- I recently installed curses with `pip install curses`
- I found a couple tutorials online (https://www.devdungeon.com/content/curses-programming-python, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbasThWVb-c)
- I always constantly testrun my code when I install a new package or learn something new

Whenever I run `s = curses.initscr()` in IDLE, I get this error message:

```
  File "C:/Users/jacob/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/screentest.py", line 3, in <module>
    s = curses.initscr()
  File "C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

This is the message from PyCharm:

```
Redirection is not supported.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And when I run a sample snippet from DevDungeon,

```
print("Preparing to initialize screen...")
screen = curses.initscr()
print("Screen initialized.")
screen.refresh()

curses.napms(2000)
curses.endwin()

print("Window ended.")
```

in command prompt with python booted, it just gives an uninteractable blank screen.

Is the thing happening in shell correct?

What the hell is going on?

How can I fix this?

please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

`sys.__stdout__` is the original sys.stdout for a python process.  When you start python with pythonw.exe, which only exists on Windows, python initially executes `stdout = __stdout__ = None`. (I am not sure about what happens on *nix.)  pythonw.exe is used to run python with a GUI UI without an associated text console.  On Windows, the IDLE icons and Start menu entries run python with pythonw.  Same with other GUI IDEs.

`curses` runs with text terminals or consoles.  It assumes that `sys.__stdout__` is such.  It cannot work when `sys.__stdout__` is None.

If you start IDLE from a command line terminal/console with `python -m idlelib`,  `sys.__stdout__` will be that terminal, and it will have a fileno().  What will happen after that I do not know.  If your program uses curses, you are likely better off to run it in the text console.